# Generate Named Destinations or bookmarks in PDF using headless chrome

Tags: html, pdf, bookmarks, google-chrome-headless

I am writing a program to generate PDF files using html-to-pdf in headless chrome. But one of the requirements is that the generated PDF should be scrollable to some destination using pre-defined anchors. This can be achieved with named destinations or bookmarks in PDF. I am wondering whether that can be achieved in headless chrome.
I have seen some stack overflow questions regarding this and some answers are two years old. Does headless chrome support either bookmarks or named destinations now?

If so can I know how to add it in the HTML so the generated PDF will have bookmarks or named destinations?

Answer (score 4):

As for February 18, 2021 it's not supported. Here is the related [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=781797) in chrome. [Wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) has this feature but sometimes it doesn't work well with modern js and HTML.